# How to define cell values to the same column for each worksheet in the workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, worksheet

I'm trying to define cell values for a column and repeat this for each worksheet in the current workbook. Here is my code for testing a simple example. It only works for the current active worksheet, while not the other worksheets. What's the problem in the code?

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            Range("F2").Value = "1"
            Range("F3").Value = "2"
            Range("F2:F3").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some '.' with `With`

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            .Range("F2").Value = "1"
            .Range("F3").Value = "2"
            .Range("F2:F3").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("F2:F21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect now! I also found another method. Inside the For loop, change the code to:

           ws.Range("F2").Value = "1"
           ws.Range("F3").Value = "2"
           ws.Select
           ws.Range("F2:F3").Select
           Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("F2:F21"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Comment: You will want to avoid `Select` and `Selection` in your macros. It's slow and generally useless. Plenty of such remarks on SO.